# Unable to receive parse.com notification with API

Tags: ios, notifications

In my iOS app I'm using parse.com as framework to send push notification. On server side we are using the parse.com rest API to generate a notification.
When I generate the notification by using this: https://www.parse.com/apps/(appName)/push_notifications/new the device receive the notification, but when I try to generate the notification by using the custom solution on my server the device doesn't receive any notification.
I looked on this page: https://www.parse.com/apps/(appName)/push_notifications and I saw the notification from API worked like the notification I ended from the parse service.
Why it doesn't work when I create the notification by my custom server?
Can you help me?
Thank you

Comment: Is there any code from the custom solution?

Comment: I developed only the app, I don't have the server code, you guess that the problem is on the server side? I asked to the person who developed the server code and he said me that all it's working fine, but maybe something is not correctly on the server code

Comment: Depending on what the push notifications are for, some can be pushed through from the app like messages between users

Comment: Maybe I found the problem: I'm watching this page: https://www.parse.com/apps/(appName)/collections and I saw that only a few devices have in the column "channels" some entries. We decided to set the channel of notification by parse `installationId`. My app send the parse `installationId`when user log in the app and we use it to assign a specific user to a specific channel. So I guess that the server doesn't assign the correct channel to my device and parse send the notification but I don't receive them because I've not the correct channel set. So I guess it's a server issue